# GWT (Maven plugin): how to enable assert checking for server side code?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, gxt

Basically I put a lot of 'assert's allover the service code (server side). I just realized that those were ignored as the execution went through upon hitting 'false' resulting expressions. However, to my surprise, assertions on the client side got checked.

I tried the following to no success.

```
mvn gwt:debug -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xmx1536m -Xms1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -ea"
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried using `-esa` also?

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not pass VM arguments to java executables started from maven (e.g. unit tests). You have to specify those variables in maven pom.

The surefire plugin supports an additional setting attribute called "argLine" for that, just as an example.