# Which one is better, object creation or simple expression evaluation?

Tags: java, junit

A little background, I'm hitting a situation where I haven't been able to enable assertions (asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789635/gwt-maven-plugin-how-to-enable-assert-checking-for-server-side-code)) and using a great solution like [forceassertions](http://scg.unibe.ch/staff/adriankuhn/javacompiler/forceassertions) is not possible for me because of [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2011/07/19/making-lombok-aspectj-and-maven-co-exist).

Assertions have always been a formidable weapon for us during the development and testing phase and we're not prepared to let it go.

That being the case, 2 options came into my mind.
The first, much like JUnit's Assert class:

```
Assert.assertTrue(result.financialInfoDTO.getPeriods().size() <= FinancialInfoConstants.NUMBER_OF_VISIBLE_PERIOD);
```

The second, trying to mimic Java's native assert keyword behaviour where we can enable or disable it:

```
    Assert.assert(new Assertion() {
       public boolean doAssert() { return result.financialInfoDTO.getPeriods().size() <= FinancialInfoConstants.NUMBER_OF_VISIBLE_PERIOD; }
    });
```

I would like to have the luxury to enable and disable the assertion feature, which only solution I can think of is something like the later. What I am asking is, given most assertion would be comparing the size of collections and comparing values of some sort, would we better off using the first option or the later?

To put it in a more technical context, which is more efficient? evaluating simple expression or creating new objects in the heap all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Object instantiation is usually more expensive. You can benchmark it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I will choose option 1.

1. It prevents from the creation of a new anonymous class and the
   instanciation of this object each time you pass through your code.
2. With the second option you are accessing an object
   (`result`) defined outside of your assertion class.
3. That's the first reason, don't you think that first one is more readable?